# Removing characters from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get my head around this for hours, but haven't found a solution yet (also here on SE).
My problem is as follows:
I created a list by parsing a HTML table via Beautifulsoup, which gives me the following:

```
results = [[None, ' Windows 64 bit\n\t\t'], ['\n\t   Official\n\t'], ['blender-2.76-3f602ff-win64.zip'], ['108M'], ['\n\t  Thu Feb 25 09:21:53 2016\n\t'], [None, ' Mac OS X 64 bit\n\t   \t\t'], ['\n\t   Official\n\t'], ['blender-2.76-ba98b68-OSX-10.6-x86_64.zip'], ['113M'], ['\n\t  Thu Feb 25 09:57:40 2016\n\t'], [None, ' Windows 32 bit\n    \t'], ['\n\t   Official\n\t'], ['blender-2.76-ba98b68-win32.zip'], ['90M'], ['\n\t  Thu Feb 25 11:33:10 2016\n\t'], [None, ' Linux 32 bit\n\t   \t\t'], ['\n\t   Official\n\t'], ['blender-2.76-3f602ff-linux-glibc211-i686.tar.bz2'], ['106M'], ['\n\t  Thu Feb 25 08:33:43 2016\n\t'], [None, ' Linux 64 bit\n\t   \t\t'], ['\n\t   Official\n\t'], ['blender-2.76-3f602ff-linux-glibc211-x86_64.tar.bz2'], ['108M'], ['\n\t  Thu Feb 25 08:33:24 2016\n\t'], ['\xa0\n'], ['\xa0\n'], ['\xa0\n'], ['\xa0\n'], ['\xa0\n']]
```

Now I want to remove the \n and \t characters, the whitespace and the \xa0\n occurrences in the end. I tried mapping the list via `results = list(map(str.strip, results))`, but nothing changes, the list stays as it is.
I'm new to Python, even after looking at other examples on here I didn't find anything that worked for me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
results = [[item.strip().strip("\xa0") if item is not None else None for item in sublist] for sublist in results]
```

Comment: "I want to remove the \n and \t characters, the whitespace..." so this will work but your `strip` is too narrow for OP's case.

Comment: What do you mean?  I remove all whitespace with `.strip()` and then I remove `"\xa0"` with `.strip("\xa0")`.  What is lacking?

Comment: Sorry I read it too quickly and my mind skipped the repeated strip call. Carry on :)

Comment: @tobkum: Glad to help.  (Especially when I get 55 reputation for it :)